# Using intents for methods

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

EDIT: Updated code:

the notificationsetter method:

```
public void notificationsetter(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Log.v("log","notificationsetter");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
    }
```

The Myreceiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String i = "Log recieved";
        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);
        Frontpage.displayNotificationActivity(context);
    }
}
```

And finally, the displaynotificationactivity method:

```
public static void displayNotificationActivity(Context context){
    int notificationIdOne = 111;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Leibniz Vertretungsplan");
    mBuilder.setContentText("Schau dir den Vertretungsplan an!");
    mBuilder.setTicker("Leibniz Vertretungsplan");
    SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String text = pref.getString("notifications_new_message_ringtone","");
    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(text));
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    SharedPreferences pref2= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean vibrate = pref2.getBoolean("notifications_new_message_vibrate",false);
    if(vibrate){
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000});
    }
    mBuilder.setLights(0xffff0000,5000,5000);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    //mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Vertretungsplanheuteactvity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Frontpage.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT //can only be used once
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdOne, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Problem: notification is not being displayed at the time I set in the calendar. Logcat says notificationsetter was used, but the onReceive method wasn't. I start the notifcationmethod with a button press, will change it in the future.

Comment: Intent(this, displayNotification()); you cannot pass a void for intent object its not going to work like that.. read about android intent.. the method is returning void..

Comment: So is there a way to set the alarm for a Method?

Comment: You have to call an acitivity with your intent : new Intent(this, Activity.class). In this class, you can call a method.

Comment: what you want to do exactly

Comment: I want to display the notification at a specific time every day. At the Moment, the notification is created in a method, which is in the mainactivity.

Comment: Refer this http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/ . hope this helps

Comment: You want to have the notification automatically appear in the list of notifications every day at a specific time?

Comment: Yes. Also, the notification is created when you use the method displayNotification();

Comment: Post the contents of `displayNotidication()` please.

Comment: Alright, look at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` class like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         MainActivity.displayNotification(context);
    }
}
```

Add this to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
```

Create the `PendingIntent` for your alarm like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

Change your `displayNotification()` method so that it takes a `Context` parameter and make it `static` (so that it can be called from `MyReceiver`). In `displayNotification()` replace all uses of `this` with `context`. You'll also need to use the `context` reference to call methods like `getApplicationContext()` and `getSystemService()`.

Should work ;-)

Comment: everything works, except the last two lines: `myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdOne, mBuilder.build());` getSystemService is a non-static method so there is a conflict if you make the method static :(

Comment: You need to call `context.getSystemService()`

Comment: Nope, nothing happens :( any thoughts on why?

Comment: Please define "nothing happens". What did you do and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well I was expecting a notification to appear, at the time I did in calendar.set: `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);` , but it didn't

Comment: Look in logcat (don't filter it). See if anything looks strange. Add logging to the `onReceive()` method to see if it is being called.

Comment: Also, after you've set the alarm you can use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to show the current state of the alarm manager. You can see if your alarm is in the list and when it is scheduled to go off and what the `PendingIntent` looks like

Comment: So the method for the alarm is working, but the alarm is probably not because onrecieve isn't called. Could you take a look at the notificationsetter() method please? Edit is in the quesiton.

Comment: You are calling `PendingIntent.getService()`. You need to call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: Please post your updated code (please correctly copy/paste from your actual source code) and your manifest.

Comment: Also, I think I have found the problem: the class myreceiver is there but the method isn't used, that's why the notification isn't appearing. Could you give me an idea where and how I should initialize the method onReceive()?

Comment: Please post your manifest too. You don't need to initialize the method `onReceive()`

Comment: oh my god. thank you. It's working, I forgot to put the `<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>` in <application> (it was first outside). Well, another lesson learned :)

Comment: one last question: I have  the notificationsetter() method currently set with a button press (not really optimal) because if I put it in the onCreate() the notification appears the moment I open the app. Same happens if I press the button some time later. Where should I put the method initialization so It sets the timer once for 7AM and repeats that every day?

Comment: You can create the Notification and schedule the alarm in `onCreate()` or wherever. `AlarmManager` has a method `setRepeating()` that you can call to have the alarm trigger every day or every hour or every whatever. Also, make sure that you aren't trying to set the alarm to go off at a time in the past (like 7AM this morning, when you do it at 9AM). If you schedule an alarm to go off at a time in the past, it triggers the alarm immediately. If you need more help please search stackoverflow there are lots of examples of alarm clocks.

Comment: Oh alright, the thing with alarm in the past explains the going off immediately ... Thank you :)